# Auto rename file when copy

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I want to copy a file to another location by `cp C:/code.txt D:/code.txt` ,any way to auto rename to `code(2).txt` or another name ,if `code.txt` was exist in D directory .Thanks much for any help !

Comment: This is tagged `linux,bash` but what's with the DOS/Windows-looking `C:, D:`?

Comment: i use Cygwin .so the directory looks like that

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer `cp --backup=numbered C:/code.txt D:/code.txt` .

Comment: Please note this is a GNU-specific option. Vanilla `cp` has no such feature.

Comment: can you help me a bit more explaination to clarify ,i am a new bie to Cygwin ,i use that command ,it runs ok

Comment: First, you're not on Linux so stop saying that (Cygwin != Linux). Second, all I'm telling you (and future readers) is that this `--backup` option only exists on GNU cp, and not (for example) on BSD cp.

Comment: So can you give me an answer if that is not GNU cp ?

Comment: @YOU: If all you care about is Cygwin, you're good - as you state, it works there. What nneonneo is trying to point out is that it won't work on _all_ Unix-like platforms, because the `--backup` option for the `cp` utility is not part of the [POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). To see if your version of `cp` is a GNU utility, run `cp --version` and examine the output; to see the `cp` features mandated by POSIX, see http://man.cx/cp

Comment: Are there alternatives to `numbered`?